# x3d compression and decompression

Tags: xml, compression, x3d

I'm using  x3d file to load 3d data for my website. The x3d files created from blender is of huge size which increases the loading time. Is there any tool/way to compress the x3d file on the fly and decompress it in user's browser to improve the loading time?

Comment: Check whether gzip compression (*.x3d.gz) is compressing enough; should be. Then browsers that indicate gzip capability can be delivered .gz. Client resp. server HTML headers Accept-Encoding, Content-Encoding. In Java EE one would use a web filter. The same for other technologies. You need a fallback though.

Comment: @JoopEggen .x3d.gz is working good by compressing nearly 70% of original size. Now I didn't catch the whole idea of http headers in html. Could you please explain more or an example of where these headers will come in html?

Comment: The client browser sends in its header an Accept-Encoding line and the server seeing that can delinver gzip compressed content with an header Content-Encoding. So this is an application feature. I do not know your options, what solution is possible. For purely static HTML (the lowest solution) [Javascript could read the client headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript),  I cannot provide a solution here. And others seem to have the same problem. If you are using/can use PHP or other server side technolgy you would have more channce.

Answer (score 0):

There's an x3d compression standard for compression:

```
[https://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19776-3/V3.1/Part03/concepts.html#X3DCompressedBinaryEncodingFileSyntax][2]
```

A quick search shows this tool supports the format:

```
[https://savage.nps.edu/X3D-Edit/][2]
```

You could also explore breaking out objects into independent files, which may or may not be possible in your case :

```
[https://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/models/inline/index.html][3]
```

Also, you could look into reducing texture image sizes, and reducing the mesh sizes with tools like Meshlab to do QECD (Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation), or use Blender's tools :

```
[https://all3dp.com/2/blender-simplify-mesh-simply-explained/][4]
```

Meshlab QECD :

```
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWM6EGVVNQU][5]
```